# Is it possible to access original function which has been overwritten in python

Tags: python, function, overwrite

I was asked to add some feature to the code originally written by other guys.
There is a python code defines a function which overwrites the build in `open` function

```
def open(xxx):
   ...
```

I would like to access original `open` function in the same python file.

The best way is to change the name of self defined `open`. But I prefer not to change it since it is a hug system which may have many other files access to this method.

So, is there a way to access the build in `open` even if it has been overwritten?

Comment: Agree that it is duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.open
<built-in function open>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.open
<built-in function open>
```

Don't use `__builtins__` :

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html):

> CPython implementation detail: Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it
>   is strictly an implementation detail. Users wanting to override values
>   in the `builtins` namespace should import the `__builtin__` (no ‘s’)
>   module and modify its attributes appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> __builtins__.open
<built-in function open>
```

Works the same in Python2 and Python3

Answer (score 2):

A more general way to access an overwritten version of a function is this:

```
oldVersionOfOpen = open
def open(...):
    oldVersionOfOpen(...)
```

In fact, functions are only variables with a value (which is a callable), so you also can assign them to other variables to store them.

You could even do it like this:

```
def newOpen(...):
    pass  # do whatever you'd like to, even using originalOpen()

originalOpen, open = open, newOpen  # switch
```